# How to change direction of arrow in d3plus ring

Tags: javascript, d3plus

How to change the arrow direction to `target` to `source` from `source` to `target` as per documentation it says to use an `Object` in the `.edges( Array | Object | url )` method. [D3plus Documentation](https://github.com/alexandersimoes/d3plus/wiki/Visualizations#edges).
Complete code is as follows to get to know about the arrow direction.

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="//d3plus.org/js/d3.js"></script>
<script src="//d3plus.org/js/d3plus.js"></script>
<div id="viz"></div>
<script>
  var connections = [
{"source": "alpha", "target": "beta"},
{"source": "alpha", "target": "gamma"},
{"source": "alpha", "target": "delta"},
{"source": "alpha", "target": "epsilon"},
{"source": "alpha", "target": "peta"},
{"source": "alpha", "target": "zeta"},
{"source": "alpha", "target": "eta"}
  ]
var visualization = d3plus.viz()
    .container("#viz")  
    .type("rings")      
    .edges(connections) 
    .edges({"direction":{"accepted":["source","target"],"value":"source"}})
    //.adeges({"direction":{"accepted":["source","target"],"value":"target"}})
    .edges({"arrows":true,"color":"#000000"})
    .focus("alpha")     
    .draw()
</script>
```

Console message.
[image: Console Message]

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZmCNWhwEBWqZv54EUHgT?p=preview

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/ESUPf56qAPtz7HMjuaOj?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="//d3plus.org/js/d3.js"></script>
<script src="//d3plus.org/js/d3plus.js"></script>
<div id="viz"></div>
<script>
    var connections = [
        {"source": "alpha", "target": "beta"},
        {"source": "alpha", "target": "gamma"},
        {"source": "alpha", "target": "delta"},
        {"source": "alpha", "target": "epsilon"},
        {"source": "alpha", "target": "peta"},
        {"source": "alpha", "target": "zeta"},
        {"source": "alpha", "target": "eta"}
    ]
    var visualization = d3plus.viz()
    .container("#viz")  
    .type("rings")      
    .edges(connections) 
    .edges({"arrows":true, "color":"#000000"})
    .edges({"arrows": { "value": ["source","target"], "direction": "source"}})
    .focus("alpha")     
    .draw()
</script>
```

Comment: please check this one. I'm trying to pass a callback function to direction key.
https://plnkr.co/edit/rAWth5FHRhKHRVAZDZdF?p=info